# How to programmability use the typescript module to get typescript errors and warnings?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use the typescript module to programmatical detect typescript errors. Here is what I have so far (much simplified):

```
var ts=require('typescript')

var file_content=`
interface Message{
  a:string
  b:number
}
var a:Message={a:'hello'}  
`
var options={
  compilerOptions:{
    module:'ES2015',
    target:'ES2015',
    inlineSourceMap:true
  },
  reportDiagnostics: true
}
const typescript_output = ts.transpileModule(file_content,options)
console.log(typescript_output.diagnostics)
```

The problem is, when running the code using node, it always prints out an empty array for the diagnostics, even though there is a typescript error in the content of *file_content* variable.

My question is: What is the correct typescript module API to get the typescript errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[transpileModule doesn't report type errors, by design](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51962). Per [the wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#a-minimal-compiler), you need to actually create a full compiler to get diagnostic messages. Using their sample code, your type errors are reported correctly:

```js
const ts = require('typescript')

function compile (fileNames, options) {
  const program = ts.createProgram(fileNames, options)
  const emitResult = program.emit()

  const allDiagnostics = ts
    .getPreEmitDiagnostics(program)
    .concat(emitResult.diagnostics)

  allDiagnostics.forEach(diagnostic => {
    if (diagnostic.file) {
      const { line, character } = ts.getLineAndCharacterOfPosition(diagnostic.file, diagnostic.start)
      const message = ts.flattenDiagnosticMessageText(diagnostic.messageText, '\n')
      console.log(`${diagnostic.file.fileName} (${line + 1},${character + 1}): ${message}`)
    } else {
      console.log(ts.flattenDiagnosticMessageText(diagnostic.messageText, '\n'))
    }
  })

  const exitCode = emitResult.emitSkipped ? 1 : 0
  console.log(`Process exiting with code '${exitCode}'.`)
  process.exit(exitCode)
}

const options = {
  compilerOptions: {
    module: 'ES2015',
    target: 'ES2015',
    inlineSourceMap: true
  },
  reportDiagnostics: true
}

compile(process.argv.slice(2), options)
```

The one downside I see here is that this requires files on disk, which is diffferent from your approach of passing a string. If someone else doesn't know of a better-suited API, you could get around this limitation by using a tempfile.

Comment: thank you so much, it does work now. files on disk is just fine for my use case

Comment: follow up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76037756/typescript-createprogram-function-seems-to-ignore-the-options-variable